# can't allow USB debugging with xperia XA1

Tags: android

I'm trying to unistall an app system(it's spotify...) without rooting my phone.

I'm new to the concepts related to android and I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/)

So I'm on the step **10** where I need to allow USB debugging to my computer 
but when i press "ok", there is the following message : "Because an app is obscuring a permissions request, Settings cannot verify your response" and then I can't grant connexion to my pc.

Does someone know what can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your phone and I don't know what apps you have installed so I don't know the exact cause, but this most commonly happens when you have an app installed that has the "draw over other apps" setting enabled.  Find the app at fault and either delete it or try to turn off the "draw over other apps" setting for the offending application.

What the error message is trying to communicate is that the button to grant permissions for the application can't be clicked because something is covering up the prompt buttons.

Comment: Ok thanks for the response i know what to do now, but i don't really know which app i causing the trouble. Maybe i have an app called "AVG Protection" so i'll try to turn off its "draw over other apps" option and i'll see

Comment: @CramikazZze have you just accepted an answer without even verifying that the solution works?

Comment: Actually it helped me to understand and solved my problem so it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem when there is FB chathead on screen or when I set display overlay, etc But, I don't have XA1. Hope this can help other people.

Answer (score 0):

Reset default settings and turn off the "draw over other apps" setting for none default apps and it should be working.

Settings --> General --> Apps --> Top right dots --> Reset App Preferences.